# Printing from IE8 Shrink-To-Fit Strange Behavior

Tags: windows-xp, printing, internet-explorer-8

Everything works fine in our testing environments.  We have "Shrink-to-fit" enabled on the print preferences to avoid things from running off the edge of the screen.  At a handful of customer locations, the shrink-to-print is not doing its job.  When you do a print preview, it goes off the edge.  Now for the strange part.  From within the print preview window, changing the orientation to landscape and back to portrait and it shrinks to fit perfectly.  Change the zoom option from "Shrink to fit" to any other number and then back, and it shrinks to fit perfectly.  But it never gets it right when you first go in or if you just print without previewing.  What is causing this nonsense?

Comment: See my answer on 
http://superuser.com/questions/62308/ie8-printing-issue-shrink-to-fit-is-not-shrinking-right-side-getting-hacked

Answer (score 1):

I ran into identical shrink-to-fit strangeness on a IE8 and Windows XP machine. Similarly, I didn't run into the problem on another machine. Both machines were running identical versions of IE8 (8.0.6001.18702). I tried restarting the machine exhibiting problems to no avail. However, after running Windows Update to install a whole host of Windows updates, the problem disappeared. So it seems like one of these updates fixed things, but since I bulk installed a whole bunch of updates, I'm not entirely sure which one. In any event, running Windows Update might magically fix this strange bug.

In case it's useful, here's the full list of updates I installed today, one of which seemed to fix things. KB2618444 and KB2544521 are the only ones that look explicitly IE related, but neither mention anything about printing...

- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP x86 (KB2656352)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows XP, Server 2003, Vista, Server 2008 x86 (KB2657424)
- **Windows XP** - Update for Windows XP (KB2633952)
- **Windows XP** - Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool - December 2011 (KB890830)
- **Windows XP** - Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 8 for Windows XP (KB2618444)
- **Office 2007** - Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 suites (KB2596785)
- **Office 2007** - Update for Microsoft Office 2007 suites (KB2596651)
- **Office 2007** - Update for Microsoft Office 2007 suites (KB2596789)
- **Office 2007** - Security Update for Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007 (KB2596912)
- **Office 2007** - Security Update for Microsoft Office Publisher 2007 (KB2596705)
- **Office 2007** - Update for Microsoft Office Excel 2007 (KB2596596)
- **Office 2007** - Security Update for Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007 (KB2596764)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2633171)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2620712)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2619339)
- **Windows XP** - Cumulative Security Update for ActiveX Killbits for Windows XP (KB2618451)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2639417)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2624667)
- **Windows XP** - Update for Windows XP (KB2641690)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2544893)
- **Office 2007** - Update for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 Junk Email Filter (KB2596560)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2564958)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP x86 (KB2518864)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2592799)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP x86 (KB2572073)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 SP1 on Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows Server 2008 x86 (KB2572067)
- **Office 2007** - Security Update for the 2007 Microsoft Office System (KB2553074)
- **Office 2007** - Update for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 (KB2583910)
- **Office 2007** - Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 System (KB2553089)
- **Office 2007** - Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 System (KB2553090)
- **Office 2007** - Security Update for Microsoft Office 2007 System (KB2584063)
- **Office 2007** - Security Update for Microsoft Office Excel 2007 (KB2553073)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2570947)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2536276)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2570222)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP x86 (KB2539631)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2566454)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2567680)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2507938)
- **Office 2007** - Microsoft Office File Validation Add-in
- **Windows XP** - Update for Windows XP (KB2541763)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Internet Explorer 8 for Windows XP (KB2544521)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2476490)
- **Office 2007** - Security Update for Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007 (KB2510061)
- **Office 2007** - Update for Microsoft Office 2007 System (KB2539530)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2535512)
- **Windows XP** - Security Update for Windows XP (KB2510531)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, will try to run updates as soon as I can.

Comment: Several machines exhibiting the problem have been reported to be up to date.  Phooey :(